# Detrending multiple signals

Tags: filters, time-series

I have multiple time series coming from pings of phone applications in a specific area.
I am suspecting that the signal is sometimes bigger and sometimes lower not because the actual signal is bigger but due to technical things (like more people downloaded the application, or the application optimized something in their process so I get more data).
I want to identify these trends in the signal and remove it in order to clean the signal from these inconsistencies.

On one side, I want to get rid of the trend created by the technical issues, on the other side I want keep the signal due to the actual number of phones in the area.

I guess I could use some kind of comparison between the signals and understand which trend is due to the real number and each is due to the provider. But I am not sure how to proceed ?
How would you do it ?
Thanks !

Comment: Can you explaing the setup a little bit more please? The reasons behind why the round-trip would fluctuate are not exactly typical. Why would the round-trip time (ping) be affected by the amount of downloads or any fluctuations in the efficiency by which an application works? And how does that lead to more data making it your way?

Comment: to be more clear, I don't have access to the inner workings of the applications. I get the pings that's all I have. For example I am seeing in the records that at some date the average number of pings augmented. I suspect this is not due to a real change in the population but to a change in the "sampling" (not sure this is the right word) method.

Comment: I see. I guess what I am trying to understand is what your data looks like. So, you have logs (?) that describe a ping. The log "tags" the round trip time value (possibly an integer) with an "app name" (?) and possibly the I.P. of the client (?) and a timestamp (?). Then from the IP of the client you can geolocate and through that geolocation also distinguish the provider (?). What I do not understand is which applications and why would they ping the (a?) server. Is this as part of a particular framework?

Comment: I think I need to reformulate this question, I'll try to come up with a clearer version. Thanks for your interest !